# PHP basic comparison with negative

Tags: php

I cannot find an answer to this and I am sure it is right in front of me. How do I say in PHP as part of an IF statement the following:

```
if NOT ( (variable1 == 10) && (variable2 == 20) )
```

Thanks!

Comment: `if( !((variable1 == 10) && (variable2 == 20)) )`

Comment: This is what I thought but it is hanging my page load... hmmm thanks will keep trying

Comment: Just for future reference variables have `$` in front of them... like `$variable`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `!` to achieve this

```
if ( (variable1 != 10) || (variable2 != 20) )
```

Or simply

```
if (!((variable1 == 10) && (variable2 == 20)))
```

Comment: I think your first answer is wrong, when you not the expression the && must be switched to an or because of demorgans law

Comment: | |  not  &&  because NOT(&&) = | |

Answer (score 0):

```
if NOT ( (variable1 == 10) && (variable2 == 20) )
```

==>

```
if (! ( (variable1 == 10) && (variable2 == 20) ) )

                    <==>

if  ( (variable1 != 10) ||(variable2 != 20) )
```

Answer (score 0):

! mean not
so U can use it like this

```
if (! ( ($variable1 == 10) && ($variable2 == 20) ) )
```

or

```
if  ( ($variable1 != 10) ||($variable2 != 20) )
```

&& will be || because !&& = ||

and U can't use variable1 without $ if U don't define it like this
`define('variable1','value of variable1');`
but then U can't change it's value so if statement will always have the same result and for that U should use $variable1